# ExtensionMethod specific to a class, property or method

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I prefer to use a lot of extension methods, asin `ToFloat`, `ToInt`, `ToLoong`, `ToGuid`, `ToSqlParameter`

Now since i've been working at my current location, some people have been complaining about the sheer amount of extension methods they see on every day objects.

For my question i'll sue the example: "ToSqlParameter"

```
    public static SqlParameter ToSqlParameter(this object source, string name, bool structured = false)
    {
        var para = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = name, Value = source };
        if (structured) { para.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured; }
        return para;
    }
```

Currently, each object will have the extension method available.

I know that adding something like `where T : class` will only make it work on classes, but since this method should be able to be used on `string`, `bool`, and even `objects` there's nothing I can do about it.

Now my question, is it possible to create the extension method so that it can only be used if applied to a `List<SqlParameter>`

Like :

```
var str = "Some Strnig";
var list = new List<SqlParameter>();
var list2 = new List<string>();
list.Add(str.ToSqlParameter("@str")); //Should work
list2.Add(str.ToSqlParameter("@str")); //Should return 'SqlParameter not found'
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Personally, I'm not a big fan of adding extension methods to commonly used types; especially primitive types because it can often pollute the intellisense for other non-applicable objects. Why don't you create some `SqlBuilder` dedicated class instead which has methods (like `AddParameter(object value, string name)`) that build the `List<SqlParameter>` instead? This way you have a dedicated class and it doesn't interfere with any common usage of basic types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, basically. The resolution happens based only on the type of `str` - what happens outside of that (`list.Add` / `list2.Add`) is irrelevant to the resolution of `ToSqlParameter`.

I do have to agree with your colleagues - it is usually not a great idea to extend `object` or an unconstrained `T`, because of the adverse impact on discovery. You *could* perhaps put all these extension methods in a very particular namespace (`Foo.Bar.DbHelpers`, for example) so that they are not visible *all the time* (only when `using` that namespace).

Another option would be to extend the *list itself* - i.e. `this IList<SqlParameter>` or similar.

Comment: I, personally, have an interest in your answer, Marc.  We, too, use a sizable number of extension methods, and they extend about all of the base types, Int32, String, Object, Double, etc.  Would you please expand on what you mean by the _impact on discovery_?  Are we setting the table for trouble later by doing what we're doing?

Comment: +1 for the "separate namespace" suggestion in particular.  Not enough people do this when adding extension methods!

Comment: @DonBoitnott what I mean is that if, every time you press `.`, you see a silly number of methods ***most of which you aren't likely to want right now***, then that is a hinderence

Comment: Since I type everything I use, or atleast a small partian of it. This does not annoy me, even if the list is longer with 200 extension methods. Thus it's hard for me to understand that people actually do get bothered by this. However, I like the idea on giving them a personal name space / class

Answer (score 4):

No, this is not possible.

Extension methods are only discovered due to the type you're trying to invoke them on, not based on the surrounding context.

Your last line of code in question would get a different error, in that the result of `ToSqlParameter` cannot be added to the list, but the method would be available.

The only way to "filter" extension methods are by:

1. The type they can be invoked on, which is not an option here since you want it on `object`
2. By namespace and thus by where you explicitly add a `using X;` directive to make it available.

If, on the other hand, all objects can be simply wrapped in a SqlParameter, here's a different approach, use reflection.

Here's a prototype (not tested):

```
public static void AddParameters(this SqlCommand command, object parameters)
{
    foreach (var propertyInfo in parameters.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        object propertyValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(parameters, null);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + propertyInfo.Name, propertyValue);
    }
}
```

You would use it like this:

```
public void DeletePersonById(int id)
{
    var cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = ...
    cmd.CommandText = "delete from persons where person_id = @id");
    cmd.AddParameters(new { id });
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    ...
```

Note that this method only creates very basic `SqlParameter` objects, you would probably want to expand this to handle special types better, like strings with sizes and such.

For a more complete example of some basic code I use for simple programs, look here: [Dropbox link to SO16962113.linq](https://www.dropbox.com/s/92tgeznatn7tz3w/SO16962113.linq). It's a [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) program that you can run that will create a SQL Server database locally and set up some dummy data for a query.

The pertinent syntax (the methods are implemented in the LINQPad program):

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection("...").AutoOpen())
{
    // prepare a fresh new database
    conn.Execute("if exists (select * from sysdatabases where name = 'SO16962113') drop database SO16962113");
    conn.Execute("create database SO16962113");
    conn.Execute("use SO16962113");

    // execute some queries
    conn.Execute("create table persons (person_id int primary key not null identity(1,1), person_name varchar(100))");
    conn.Execute("insert into persons (person_name) values ('James'), ('Jon'), ('Mary'), ('Jack')");
    conn.Query<Person>("select * from persons where person_id in (@id1, @id2)", new { id1 = 2, id2 = 4 }).Dump();

    // clean up
    conn.Execute("use master");
    conn.Execute("drop database SO16962113");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No that wouldn't be possible, but one possible solution would be to `namespace` your extension methods in so much that those leveraging them would add `using` statements for the ones that made sense.

See, if I knew I was going to do some casting, but wasn't dealing with any `SqlParameter` objects then I'd just add `using Extensions.Casting;` and I'd have a smaller subset of methods.